# Dynamic menu with reactJs and MySQL, Mainmenu and submenus

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, reactjs

**Update 9 oct 2019:**

Now I have done a dropdown as well, I haven´t got an answer yet on my problem, and took the question out on another forum. To make it easier with all the old and new code I just take out the link to the forum itself: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/creating-a-dynamic-menu-with-reactjs-and-mysql/320491
 If you know anything, when you have seen the updated code on this link I would be really thankful of some answers either here on stack Overflow or the other forum, thank you.

**Old code:**

I have been stuck about one week now to create a dynamic menu with submenus with reactJs and MySQL. I did an image in paint to show how I want the result to be:

[Dynamic menu, with submenus end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOpCy.png)

Right now I have connected so you can see all the images dynamic, meaning it get the information I have where (source) my pictures are from my database itself. Find the images from my folder structure that I have and print it out on the screen.

My problem is that I want to create a dynamic menu with submenus like I have on my image above. I have searched around a lot in google/youtube but for me I have just found solutions that is either hardcoded or just using reactJs.

I need to make my structure to work with both reactJs and MySQL database. I have seen a lot about ul = unordered list and li tags , and also select/options tags. But I would be really thankful if anyone could show me a solution that will work for me. How would you solve it?

Here is my menus table in MySQL database:

[menus table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHMhL.png)

The data I have taken inside the browse tab:

[under the menus table I have this data inside the browse tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24OZH.png)

My code this far:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './sass/style.scss';
import Admin from "./components/routes/Admin";
import Test from "./components/Test";




class App extends Component {
  render() {
/* klassen Homepage ska till Homepage.js komponenten senare */
      return (
      <div className="App">

        <Admin />

        <p className="TEST"> lorem imsum </p>


        <div className="homepage">

            <div className="container_header">
            </div>

           <div className="container_menu">
                <Test />
            </div>

            <div className="container_stats">
            </div>

            <div className="container_facts">
            </div>

            <div className="container_footer">
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

fetchMenu.php:

```
<?php
    /* This file fetches all the DropdownMenu buttons from the SQL database table menus and order the buttons by id. */
    include_once 'database.php';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM menus ORDER BY id ASC");
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Test.js:    Which will be the DropdownMenu component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.scss";

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      allMenus: [],
      picUrl: '../images/Buttons/main_menu_dragons.png;'
    };
  }

 handleDragonMenuClick = DisplaySubMenu => () => {
    this.setState({
      picUrl: DisplaySubMenu
    });
  };

  fetchAllMenus = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost/dragonology/server/fetchMenu.php")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ allMenus: data });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchAllMenus();
  }

  renderMenus = () =>
    this.state.allMenus
      .filter(menu => menu.parentId !== null)
      .map(menu => (
        <div key={menu.id}>
          <img src={menu.picUrl} alt={menu.picName} />
        </div>
      ));

/* If you take away the ! mark the mainMenu will be able to show, but not the subMenu*/
renderMainMenu = () =>
    this.state.allMenus
      .filter(menu => menu.parentId == null)
      .map(menu => (
        <div key={menu.id}>
          <img src={menu.picUrl} alt={menu.picName} />
        </div>
      ));

   renderSubmenu = () =>
    this.state.allMenus
      .filter(menu => menu.parentId === 2)
      .map(menu => (
        <div key={menu.id}>
          <a href={menu.linkUrl}>
            <img src={menu.picUrl} alt={menu.picName} />
          </a>
        </div>
      ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Menu">


<button onClick={this.handleDragonMenuClick('renderMenus :')}><div>{this.renderMainMenu()}</div></button>
        <div id="sub_2">{this.renderMenus()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

If you have any questions/want more information feel free to contact me. I´m thankful for all input I get :)

Comment: can you share your code via codesandbox?

Comment: @chin8628 Hello there thank you for your respond. I have heard of codesandbox but I haven´t used it before. I can check it out tomorrow and see if I can add the code there :)

Comment: Um can you send a sandbox with out get my github account connected or how does it work?
What does it mean when my github account gets connected? Will it show all I have or a specific project? and if so can others just go in and change the content in it how they want or does this just creates a copy of it all that others can play around with out changing the orginal?

Comment: it doesn't require any github account. You can create anonymous codesandbox, then share a link here. https://codesandbox.io

Comment: @chin8628 I have tried today to take in my code into the codesandbox with no success. How does the codesandbox know my database? I don´t know either how I shall take in images here? Also im using sass so seems now it doesnt even connect that. So more questions than answers. Arent it another way?

Comment: Now I have done a dropdown as well, I haven´t got an answer yet on my problem, and took the question out on another forum. To make it easier with all the old and new code I just take out the link to the forum itself: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/creating-a-dynamic-menu-with-reactjs-and-mysql/320491
 If you know anything, when you have seen the updated code on this link I would be really thankful of some answers either here on stack Overflow or the other forum, thank you.